# How can same role users edit other posts

Tags: wordpress

I have added one user role account and under account role there are 2 users. For example A and B are two users. The problem is A user cannot edit B user post and vice versa. But my requirement is same role users can edit each other posts. Can some one help me how can I do this?

Comment: You may use buildin roles. Assign "Editor" to both. This should work